# Show that there exists $a^* \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ such that $f(a^*) \leq f(a)$, $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, polynomials

> Let $h \in C[0,1]$. Show that there exists $a^* \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$
>   such that $P_{a^*}$ best approximates $h$ in quadratic mean. Let $f :
>  \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ define as
>   $f(a)=\int_0^1(h(t)-P_a(t))^2dt$. Show that there exists $a^* \in
>  \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ such that $f(a^*) \leq f(a)$, $\forall a \in
>  \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$.

I think we have to use the following result to show that the function is coercive.

> **Result for the problem :** For $a= (a_0, \dots , a_k) \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$, we define the polynomial of degree $k$ $$P_a :
>  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$P_a(t)=a_0+a_1t+ \dots + a_k t^k.$$ Let
>   $$g :\mathbb{R}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$g(a) =
>  \int_0^1(P_a(t))^2dt.$$ A result explain that there exists $\alpha >
>  0$ such that $g(a) \geq \alpha \|a\|^2.$

**Well-known theorem :** Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ a close set, the continuous function $f : C \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{\|x\| \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$. Then $\exists x_n \in C$ such $f(x_n) \leq f(x)$, $\forall x \in C$.

Is anyone could resolve this problem? I don't think I have all the skills to do that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality: Note

$$\begin{split}
f(a) &= \int_0^1 (h(t) - P_a(t))^2 dt \\
&= \int_0^1 P_a(t)^2 dt + \int_0^1 h(t)^2 dt - 2\int_0^1 h(t) P_a(t) dt \\
&\ge\int_0^1 P_a(t)^2 dt + \int_0^1 h(t)^2 dt - 2\sqrt{\int_0^1 h(t)^2 dt} \sqrt{\int_0^1 P_a(t) ^2 dt} \\
&= g(a) + C^2 - 2C\sqrt{g(a)}
\end{split}
$$

where we write $C = \sqrt{\int_0^1 h(t)^2 dt}$, which is fixed independent of $a$. Try to use this and your results to show that $f$ is coercive.

Edit: Note that the last term on the right is 
$$ (\sqrt {g(a)} -C)^2.$$

Now, to show that $f$ is coercive, let $a\in \mathbb R^{n+1}$ be big, so that $\|a\| > \frac{C}{\sqrt\alpha}$. So $\sqrt{g(a)} -C \ge \sqrt{\alpha} \| a\| -C >0$. Thus

$$f(a) \ge (\sqrt{g(t)} -C)^2 > (\sqrt{\alpha} \|a\| - C)^2.$$

If $\|a\|\to \infty$, the right hand side also goes to infinity. So

$$\lim_{a\to \infty} f(a) = \infty.$$

Comment: Good work, but I think you miss a $2$ somewhere, because $(a-b)^2=a^2+-2ab + b^2$. :)

Comment: @Pineuf : Yes, edited.

Comment: I have some difficulties to show that $f$ is coercive. Could you explain to me how?

Comment: @Pineuf : Please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

The space of all polynomial coefficients up to degree $k$ are of finite dimension $k+1$, hence it is closed. The function $f$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
f(a) = \|h-P_{a}\|_{L^2(0,1)}^2. 
\end{equation}
I think we can show that $\lim_{\|a\| \to \infty}f(a) = \infty$ by taking $a_0\to \infty$ while setting the others to 0.